# How can I import .woff fonts my site

Tags: html, css, .net, fonts, webfonts

I'm using @font-face on my  site and it does not work, 404 error on the .woff file.  I have the fonts located at the root but  could not find fonts

this is my font css file what is problem?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '---_2regular';
    src: url('----regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('----regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('----regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('----regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('---regular-webfont.svg#---_2regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must contact your Hosting company. Then They must add .woff extension to mime types.
Possible, your problem can been solved.

Answer (score 0):

All you can read about woff and having them on your site:

http://www.google.com/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your fonts located in the same directory as the css file, unless you have specified a path otherwise.

Give http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator a try, it gives an example HTML page with the font embedded, hopefully it should point you in the right direction!